# PHP tag interpretation

Tags: support, code-formatting

Hi there,

A little while ago I wanted to help someone correct his/her code by posting a piece of code with an echo in it. To my suprise, only the text that the code was supposed to echo appeared in my post:

View Companies

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url().'company/view'; ?>">View Companies</a></li>
```

I'm just wondering if this is supposed to happen? -is it part of the security, or so you can provide a real-life example? (bug or feature?)

Just thought I'd ask, because I couldn't find a topic about it, sorry.

Comment: Make sure you're escaping your code by indenting it 4 spaces or wrapping it with ``back ticks``

Answer (score 1):

Indent 4 spaces, as defined in

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

which is linked from

- the small [?] to the upper right of every edit area
- the "full reference >> " link in the sidebar of any ask or edit page
- the /faq

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess my question was a little vague. What I meant to ask, is if it's normal that the site accepts php scripts as actual scripts unless you use back ticks or 4 spaces. But I guess it is, to some extent.

Comment: @choseal HTML is allowed here